# How to stack columns under each-other with Flexbox? Can't get layout working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having problems trying to stack two divs under each other on the right-hand side alongside a content area div.

Like so,

`content area | right div 1
              | right div 2`

However, they all just sit inline in 3 columns. I want 2 columns, column 1 then the right side 2 divs under each other.

I need these 2 divs not to be wrapped in a container or `aside` as I want div 2 to use `position: sticky`

Here is a demo:
https://codepen.io/pbul2004/pen/xxZKyVR

```css
/* CSS */

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  max-width: 100%;
  flex-basis: 74%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 300px;
}

.right-side {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex: 1 1;
  flex-basis: 40%;
  min-width: 338px;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML:-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content area here</div>
  <div class="right-side personal-info">personal info here</div>
  <div class="right-side product-info">this div sticky</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need these 2 divs not to be wrapped in a container or aside as I want div 2 to use position: sticky

I'm not sure I understand that part of your question, but why don't you simply wrap the last two divs with a parent div?

In other words:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content area here</div>
  <div>
    <div class="right-side personal-info">personal info here</div>
    <div class="right-side product-info">this div sticky</div>
  </div>
</div>
```